# How to disable sorting in Movilizer table Columns

Tags: movilizer

In Movilizer how to disable Table columns sorting.

below is my table screen template

```
<question title="Preferrable Colors" type="9" key="#1">
            <answer nextQuestionKey="END" key=**"#1_1"** position="0">
                <text>DNO</text>
            </answer>
            <answer nextQuestionKey="END" key=**"#1_2"** position="1">
                <text>Department</text>
            </answer>
            <answer nextQuestionKey="END" key=**"#1_3"** position="2">
                <text>Location</text>
            </answer>         

        </question>
```

Please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the attribute `colSortable="false"` in the `answer` tag.